# How can I pop the back stack from a FragmentActivity to the previous activity?

Tags: android, fragment-backstack

I have a `FragmentActivity` (called "QuizActivity") in which the user navigates through a series of question fragments, taking a quiz. Once they get to the end of the quiz, they transition to a fragment (still in the QuizActivity) that shows the quiz score. From there, I would like to give the user a button that takes them back to the activity they were on before they started the QuizActivity. I specifically do *not* want this button, or the back button, to just pop the back stack, which would take the user back into the questions of the quiz they have just finished.

If `QuizActivity` were just an `Activity` instead of a `FragmentActivity`, I could call `Activity.onBackPressed()` to pop the `QuizActivity` off the back stack. But `QuizActivity` is a `FragmentActivity`, and `FragmentActivity.onBackPressed()` pops *fragments* off the back stack, one at a time.

`FragmentManager.popBackStack(id or name, POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)` should be able to do what I want, if I can find out the id or name of the first fragment in the QuizActivity. How do I find that? The first fragment is navigated to using a navigation XML file. How do I set the name of the first fragment (so I can pop back to it, inclusive), if it's in an XML navigation doc? The `android:name` attribute sets the fragment class, not the name that popBackStack would look for, I believe. Do I use `android:label`?

Or how do I determine the ID? Is it the integer value (`R.id.myFragment`) of the `android:id` attribute in the XML navigation doc? The [documentation for popBackStack(id, flags)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.html#popbackstack_1) says "The identifier is the number returned by FragmentTransaction.commit()." But since I'm not using `FragmentTransaction.commit()`, what is the ID?

I tried examining the back stack to find IDs and names, using `FragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount()`, `getBackStackEntryAt(i)`, and `BackStackEntry.getName()`. But the entry count was always zero! I don't understand how that can happen, when there is clearly a backStack: pressing the back button moves me backward through preceding fragments (questions of the quiz).

Comment: Why not just have the button start a new intent to go to the desired activity? You could put extras in the intent to keep track of the state they are in

Comment: It sounds like you want to pop the whole activity, correct? That's what the `finish()` API for Activity does. Is there a reason you aren't doing that?

Comment: @Quinn I considered that, but how do I know what desired activity to go back to? They could have come to the current activity from a couple of different places.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Yep you're right.  (Though I'd still like to know why `FragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount()` was giving zero.)

Comment: If you're using Navigation, the back stack is in the `NavHostFragment`'s `childFragmentManager`, not the Activity's FragmentManager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to call `finish()` on the `QuizActivity`

In the fragment with your button just use `activity.finish()`

Comment: Wow ... slapping my forehead (SMF).